# Override logic for creating user accounts in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, validation, meteor

In the meteor accounts package, if an existing email address exists the function will fail and the user wont be created as expected. Is there any hooks or an override that can be used to change the logic so that i can check a custom field on that `users` collection. The relevant code i am referring to is https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js?source=c#L540-L541.

My application never deletes users but instead sets a field `deleted` to true or false with server side permissions and checks that ensure who can or can't set this field. I tried to check this field in the http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_validatenewuser hook but the error happens before this function is hit. Does the same thing happen for this hook http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser ?

Comment: So to be clear, the goal is to allow creation of a user who has the same email address as an existing, deleted user?

Comment: Would you be willing to work around this by using oncreateuser to process _every_ user creation to _move_ the email address to another property of the user and subsequently carry out any other checks you want to accomplish, as well as existing email check since all other users' addresses will have been moved to your custom property.

Comment: @DavidWeldon Yes thats correct, i would like to notify the user that the email address is still in use and if this email is indeed theirs, revalidate them and create a new record.

Comment: @SerkanDurusoy Yea, would that mean removing the email address field from the deleted user first ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to remove the email, but keep it elsewhere so that meteor does not get stuck at duplicate email check. But you'll need to check it yourself.

Comment: As an alternative to deleting the old email, when a user gets deleted you could just append a '+deleted' to the local part of the address. e.g. 'foo+deleted@example.com'. That way the original address is still valid and you can search for it if you want to.

Comment: @DavidWeldon, i think that might be easier. I was thinking of validating the email of deleted users and if a match is found, asking the user to revalidate their email instead of creating records. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Warz Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Gaelan I haven't picked an approach to this problem yet. My solution however for the meantime is to notify the user of the existing email address if they want to confirm deletion by flagging the record. If they confirm by email address, I will delete the record and create a new one.